# Difference between .modal('show') and .modal()

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

If `.modal()` is used without options, it seems to behave identical to `.modal('show')`. Anything entered into form input fields in my modal remains there even after calling `.modal()` again.

Is there any difference between these two methods when not used with options? If not, is the only purpose of `.modal('show')` for backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for **initializing** the modal with the [default options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/#options):

```
$('#myModal').modal();
```

Since the default value of the `show` **option** is *true*, it's effectively the same as calling...

```
$('#myModal').modal({show:true});
```

*or*, using the `show` **method** to explicitly show the modal, regardless of the value of `show` **option**...

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

However, if you were to change the value of the `show` option to *false* (either via data-attributes or JS)..

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-show="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
         ..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Calling `$('#myModal').modal();` would *not* automatically show the modal.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/I0oPNSvX5M